# 3D trajectory reconstruction from video (taken by a single camera)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, 3d, computer-vision

I am currently trying to reconstruct a 3D trajectory of a falling object like a ball or a rock out of a sequence of images taken from an iPhone video.

Where should I start looking? I know I have to calibrate the camera (I think I'll use the matlab calibration toolbox by Jean-Yves Bouguet) and then find the vanishing point from the same sequence, but then I'm really stuck.

Comment: So, you have a stationary camera and a moving ball?

Comment: well basically yes. This is a project for a graduate course, and the assignment is to obtain the 3D trajectory out of a sequence of frames taken out a camera which has to be initially calibrated. I'm currently using the Zisserman to get an understanding of the underlying math, but it is (imho) pretty much vague in the specifics for this project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

read this: http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/courses/compsci773s1c/lectures/773-GG/lectA-773.htm
it explains 3d reconstruction using two cameras. Now for a simple summary, look at the figure from that site:

[image: 3d reconstruction from stereovision]

You only know pr/pl, the image points. By tracing a line from their respective focal points Or/Ol you get two lines (Pr/Pl) that both contain the point P. Because you know the 2 cameras origin and orientation, you can construct 3d equations for these lines. Their intersection is thus the 3d point, voila, it's that simple.

But when you discard one camera (let's say the left one), you only know for sure the line Pr. What's missing is depth. Luckily you know the radius of your ball, this extra information can give you the missing depth information. see next figure (don't mind my paint skills): [image: bal projection]

Now you know the depth using [the intercept theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem)

I see one last issue: the shape of ball changes when projected under an angle (ie not perpendicular on your capture plane). However you do know the angle, so compensation is possible, but I leave that up to you :p

edit: @ripkars' comment (comment box was too small)

1) ok

2) aha, the correspondence problem :D Typically solved by correlation analysis or matching features (mostly matching followed by tracking in a video). (other methods exist too)
I haven't used the image/vision toolbox myself, but there should definitely be some things to help you on the way.

3) = calibration of your cameras. Normally you should only do this once, when installing the cameras (and every other time you change their relative pose)

4) yes, just put the Longuet-Higgins equation to work, ie: solve

```
P = C1 + mu1*R1*K1^(-1)*p1
P = C2 + mu2*R2*K2^(-1)*p2
```

with
 P = 3D point to find
 C = camera center (vector)
 R = rotation matrix expressing the orientation of the first camera in the world frame.
 K = calibration matrix of the camera (containing internal parameters of the camera, not to be confused with the external parameters contained by R and C)
 p1 and p2 = the image points
 mu = parameter expressing the position of P on the projection line from camera center C to P (if i'm correct R*K^-1*p expresses a line equation/vector pointing from C to P)

these are 6 equations containing 5 unknowns: mu1, mu2 and P

edit: @ripkars' comment (comment box too small once again)
The only computer vison library that pops up in my mind is OpenCV (http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki ). But that's a C library, not matlab... I guess google is your friend ;)

About the calibration: yes, if those two images contain enough information to match some features. If you change the relative pose of the cameras, you'll have to recalibrate of course.

The choice of the world frame is arbitrary; it only becomes important when you want to analyze the retrieved 3d data afterwards: for example you could align one of the world planes with the plane of motion -> simplified motion equation if you want to fit one.
This world frame is *just* a reference frame, changeable with a 'change of reference frame transformation' (translation and/or rotation transformation)

Comment: Hey thank you very much Gunther this was really helpful! I'm currently looking at the website you provided, I will try to get a better understanding of this problem using that and the Zisserman :)

Comment: @Andrey: Let's see if I grasped the gist of the whole thing: <br/>
1) take a video of the same moving object using two video cameras in different poses<br/>
2) find some matching points (how? does the image processing/computer vision toolbox helps in this?) between the two videos at the same frame number<br/>
3) make an estimate of the fundamental/essential matrix  using the eight point algorithm<br/>
4) reconstruct by triangulation<br/>

Correct :)?

Comment: Thanks again Gunther! I would like to ask you if you can point me out some algorithms in particular about correlation analysis and matching features. In the worst case, I'm going to implement them myself, and possibly release them open sourced.
Moreover, for the calibration thing: so I need only two images taken from different poses, dont't I? And what if I make the world frame coincide with the frame of the first camera? Does this simplify the whole procedure?

Comment: The only library that pops up in my mind is OpenCV (http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki ).

Answer (score 4):

Unless you have a stereo camera, you will never be able to know the position for sure, even with calibrated camera. Because you don't know whether the ball *is small and close or large and far away*.

There are other methods with single camera, based on series of images with different focus. But I doubt that you can control the camera of your cell phone in that way.

**Edit(1):**
as @GuntherStruyf points out correctly, you can know the position if one of your inputs is the size of the ball.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if I calibrated the camera using a black-white square matrix of known dimension?

Comment: then you're still missing the depth information, unless you know how large the ball is. In that case you can calculate the depth from the balls diameter

Comment: ok so: how does one get depth information from single camera?

Comment: @ripkars, Either by recognizing objects (Very difficult computer vision problem) or by changing the focus and analyzing series of images.

Comment: @Andrey thanks. What if I try to fit a conic using N points and least square error? Don't I get a 3D trajectory this way?

Comment: @ripkars, you will get 2D trajectory in the plane of the pixels. But you don't know the depth.

Comment: Or, the camera could be moved, which is known as Structure from Motion.

Comment: if I am getting this right, I suppose you suggest to compute/estimate the fundamental or essential matrix from successive scenes of this moving camera and then elaborate on them as if I had multiple view cameras?