# How to find velocity of tennis ball if I have x,y coordinates?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, prediction

I am currently working on a computer vision project related to tennis.

In summary, using this [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11FqSEN_HIhzM3OZ22WoZHJnW1rvbnz4y/view?usp=sharing) and python `OpenCV` I extracted the `x,y` coordinates of the ball from every frame of the video.
Here is what I have got -
P.S. x,y coordinates are in the following [format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nmd4n.png)

```html
points = [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [985, 325], [978, 345], None, None, None, None, None, [904, 613], [895, 644], [886, 649], [877, 654], [870, 658], [870, 658], [861, 664], [853, 672], [846, 679], [837, 688], [827, 695], [827, 695], [821, 707], [812, 716], [803, 729], [1051, 313], [786, 755], [786, 755], [782, 769], [782, 746], [786, 730], [793, 700], [800, 677], [800, 677], [803, 656], [807, 640], [814, 620], [819, 593], [819, 579], [819, 579], [825, 562], [831, 546], [834, 532], None, [833, 805], [833, 805], None, None, None, None, None, None, [865, 427], [867, 418], [871, 409], [872, 400], [877, 392], [877, 392], [877, 385], [883, 377], [883, 369], [887, 366], [890, 358], [890, 357], [892, 352], [894, 346], [897, 340], [898, 336], [900, 332], [900, 332], [902, 329], [905, 325], [905, 322], [908, 320], [910, 316], [910, 316], [912, 315], [914, 314], [916, 310], [919, 308], [919, 306], [919, 306], [920, 305], [924, 306], [922, 306], [926, 305], [928, 305], [926, 307], [930, 306], [930, 305], [932, 305], [933, 307], [935, 310], [935, 308], [936, 310], [937, 313], [938, 314], [940, 316], [942, 319], [942, 319], [942, 322], [943, 323], [945, 324], [946, 316], [945, 306], [945, 306], [945, 298], [946, 291], [947, 284], [947, 278], [950, 272], [949, 273], [950, 266], [951, 261], [950, 255], [950, 251], [951, 245], [951, 245], [953, 241], [952, 237], [950, 236], [945, 237], [939, 240], [938, 239], [934, 242], [928, 244], [922, 250], [917, 252], [911, 256], [911, 256], [905, 263], [899, 267], [896, 274], [890, 278], [883, 286], [883, 286], [878, 293], [873, 300], [869, 309], [863, 318], [858, 329], [858, 329], [851, 338], [846, 349], [840, 359], [835, 371], [830, 384], [830, 384], [825, 397], [818, 410], [812, 424], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [774, 535], [773, 537], [768, 550], [761, 572], [754, 592], [750, 615], [748, 624], [748, 624], [739, 652], [733, 674], [728, 698], [727, 718], [718, 733], [718, 733], [714, 732], [709, 729], [705, 728], [702, 729], [694, 728], [696, 728], [692, 728], [688, 730], [684, 730], [678, 731], [675, 734], [675, 734], [673, 737], [667, 741], [664, 743], [659, 749], [653, 755], [653, 755], [650, 759], [647, 765], [642, 774], [636, 780], [633, 786], [633, 787], [630, 796], [625, 804], [629, 769], [634, 737], [633, 718], [633, 718], [640, 697], [644, 657], [649, 640], [651, 616], [655, 592], [654, 591], [654, 578], [656, 560], [659, 544], [662, 525], None, None, None, [668, 482], None, None, [675, 448], [675, 448], None, [677, 427], [677, 419], [678, 410], [678, 404], [678, 404], [679, 394], [682, 394], [682, 385], [682, 380], [683, 374], [683, 374], [684, 370], [684, 367], [684, 364], [685, 361], [686, 359], [686, 359], [686, 357], [686, 356], [687, 353], [686, 353], [687, 352], [687, 352], [688, 350], [687, 339], [685, 329], [687, 318], [686, 309], [687, 309], [681, 300], [686, 293], [688, 283], [689, 273], [688, 268], [689, 270], [689, 261], [688, 256], [688, 250], [689, 243], [688, 238], [688, 238], [690, 237], [690, 231], [690, 228], [691, 226], [696, 227], [699, 226], [705, 227], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [758, 234], [758, 234], [762, 239], [769, 241], [775, 243], [780, 246], [787, 250], [787, 250], [793, 253], [800, 256], [806, 261], [812, 263], [820, 266], [820, 266], [826, 271], [832, 274], [840, 279], [845, 283], [851, 289], [852, 289], [858, 296], [866, 299], [874, 306], [879, 312], [888, 318], [888, 318], [893, 323], [900, 330], [908, 338], [914, 344], [922, 350], [922, 350], [928, 360], [937, 367], [945, 378], [950, 384], None, None, [967, 402], [974, 411], [980, 421], [989, 428], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [1054, 518], [1061, 533], [1066, 543], [1076, 557], [1077, 558], [1087, 569], [1093, 585], [1101, 601], [1110, 614], [1119, 629], [1119, 629], [1128, 642], [1136, 662], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [1211, 723], [1216, 718], [1220, 719], [1226, 719], [1227, 718], [1232, 718], [1238, 719], [1243, 721], [1252, 721], [1256, 721], [1256, 721], [1262, 725], [1268, 728], [1273, 731], [1280, 734], [1286, 737], [1286, 737], [1293, 742], [1298, 746], [1305, 749], None, [1299, 691], [1299, 691], [1295, 668], [1295, 649], [1288, 623], [1285, 597], [1280, 571], [1280, 571], [1277, 552], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [1254, 430], [1249, 417], [1249, 417], [1246, 409], [1242, 399], [1239, 392], [1237, 384], [1234, 379], [1234, 379], [1231, 373], [1230, 367], [1227, 364], [1225, 361], [1222, 358], [1222, 358], [1220, 356], [1219, 353], [1214, 353], [1212, 352], [1209, 350], [1209, 350], [1207, 351], [1206, 350], [1204, 352], [1202, 350], [1202, 335], [1202, 335], [1200, 324], [1198, 313], None, [1194, 292], [1195, 281], [1195, 281], [1194, 273], [1191, 263], [1191, 256], [1191, 247], [1190, 239], [1190, 239], [1189, 234], [1189, 228], [1189, 221], [1188, 216], [1186, 213], [1187, 212], [1184, 209], [1183, 205], [1182, 200], [1181, 195], [1181, 195], [1181, 195], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [908, 212], [906, 222], [901, 235], [900, 235], [898, 249], [893, 263], [888, 276], [883, 292], [878, 303], [879, 303], [876, 321], [857, 673], [866, 349], [863, 365], [859, 384], [859, 384], [855, 398], [851, 411], [849, 412], [845, 413], [841, 414], [841, 414], [837, 414], [835, 413], [830, 415], [828, 416], [825, 416], [825, 416], [821, 419], [817, 421], [816, 424], [813, 425], [809, 423], [809, 423], [805, 405], [804, 378], [803, 360], [799, 340], [800, 324], [800, 324], [838, 625], None, [793, 274], [791, 259], [788, 248], [788, 248], [787, 235], [783, 224], [783, 214], [781, 204], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [856, 617], [857, 617], [860, 617], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [808, 210], [814, 226], [818, 239], [820, 238], [824, 250], [830, 260], [836, 275], [839, 286], None, None, [852, 321], [858, 334], [860, 350], [868, 366], [875, 383], [875, 383], [880, 402], [885, 418], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [975, 558], [991, 561], [991, 561], None, [997, 579], None, None, None, None, None, [1017, 577], None, [1028, 565], [942, 433], [942, 433], [943, 424], [944, 420], [946, 412], [949, 407], [948, 401], [948, 401], [948, 397], [949, 391], [950, 391], [952, 385], [954, 381], [954, 381], [954, 378], [954, 375], [955, 372], [956, 371], [956, 368], [956, 368], [956, 368], [960, 365], [959, 363], [960, 364], [961, 364], [961, 364], [963, 363], [963, 364], [962, 364], [965, 365], [967, 367], [967, 367], [967, 367], [966, 370], [966, 371], [968, 374], [969, 377], [969, 377], [969, 381], [969, 384], [969, 388], None, [972, 394], [972, 394], [971, 399], [972, 404], [973, 409], [972, 414], [973, 418], [973, 418], [973, 424], [973, 430], [972, 437], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [973, 430], [974, 423], [974, 416], [974, 411], [974, 407], [974, 407], [973, 403], [972, 396], None, [971, 389], [973, 385], [973, 385], [972, 384], [973, 379], [972, 377], [971, 374], [972, 373], [973, 373], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [957, 372], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [946, 412], [941, 413], [935, 414], [936, 414], [929, 414], [922, 413], [914, 414], [908, 416], [902, 417], [902, 417], [894, 418], [889, 422], [882, 424], [873, 425], [867, 428], [867, 428], [861, 436], [853, 437], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [743, 536], [738, 543], [732, 552], [732, 545], [732, 545], [734, 532], None, None, [701, 583], None, None, None, None, None, [766, 425], [770, 413], [769, 414], [774, 405], [776, 392], [780, 384], [783, 374], [788, 363], [788, 363], [791, 354], [794, 346], [799, 339], [802, 331], [805, 324], [805, 324], [808, 319], [813, 312], [814, 304], [818, 299], [824, 295], [824, 295], [828, 288], [828, 285], [832, 280], [835, 276], [838, 274], [838, 274], [842, 269], [846, 266], [848, 265], [852, 262], [855, 260], [855, 260], [857, 259], [861, 256], None, [868, 253], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [1081, 594], [1091, 586], [1091, 586], [1103, 573], [1113, 564], [1126, 553], [1140, 542], [1150, 533], [1150, 533], [1163, 523], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

These points on the [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/118i4BUbn1ddilS_41R2YffnznJT-8H1T/view?usp=sharing)
How can I determine the ball speed for every second (30 frames).
Any help, pointer, advice is appreciated.

Comment: What's the coordinate system? The tennis court plane or the video frame?

Comment: @mcsoini Thanks for asking, these points are from the whole video. I edited the question and added a video with these points.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My final goal is to find the points where the ball touches the court. So far, I have managed to track the ball, court and player [here](https://github.com/ArtLabss/tennis-tracking)

Comment: @mcsoini  Appreciate your help, I would accept you comments as an answer if would write one answer. Thanks for help and your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not straight-forward since ultimately you are missing a dimension: If the ball moves away from the camera, you have no way of knowing how fast it goes or where it is. You would need to project the trajectory into 3D space, but you don't have the information to do that. Try searching for "reconstruction of trajectory from single camera", e.g. in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259227/3d-trajectory-reconstruction-from-video-taken-by-a-single-camera).

However, it appears that people have sought various solutions for this problem: Approaches in the literature combine the information from the camera with additional information on the physical system, to overcome this issue; see e.g. a paper on soccer ball tracing [here](http://mva-org.jp/Proceedings/2013USB/papers/04-22.pdf).